# useRef Did not change the element style in React

Tags: reactjs, use-ref

okay i am trying to make a toggle display element from hidden to block and vice versa and bind it to a button.

i use useRef and it somewhat work, but only one time, it doesn't toggle again after the element display is block.

here is the code i use.

```
const handleMobileMenu = () => {
setIsPressed(!isPressed);
const state = isPressed ? "flex" : "hidden";
mobileMenu.current.style.display = state;
console.log(state); 
};
```

the console log displaying what i want which is block, hidden, block, hidden.. its toggling. but the element doesn't.

i've tried using, if else, but same problem.

Comment: Please make a reproducible example [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in any sandbox. My guess is that the component you apply the ref styles just remounts. Anyway, thats not the recommended way to apply dynamic styles in React, see `styles` prop, or just add condition on the `className`

Comment: And in this specific case, its a use case for media queries.

Comment: oh yeah i am so sorry for not following the reproducible example, this is my first time asking. okay i'll try the condition on the classname

Answer (score 0):

yup silly me, just use a conditional className, and the problem is solved.

thanks **Dennis Vash**